# How to display an email address for users but hide from robot? Is there a simply way to do it using PHP, Javascript or Jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, email, email-spam

Is there an elegant and easy/simple way to do it using PHP, Javascript or Jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the PHP imagestring() function to create an image.

```
<?php
// Create a 100*30 image
$im = imagecreate(120, 30);

// White background and blue text
$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);

// Write the email address at the top left
imagestring($im, 5, 0, 0, 'test@test.com', $textcolor);

// Output the image
header('Content-type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: What if I want the placement of image to be adaptable?

Comment: ..save the image on the web server, and load it in the html page simply with <img src="$imageurl" />

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways of doing this. We've had som luck obfuscating source via python/javascript. Another simpler favourite is the CSS unicode-bidi technique:

```
div.contact { unicode-bidi:bidi-override; direction: rtl; }
<div class="contact">moc.rab@oof</div>
```

Prints out:

foo@bar.com

Comment: But how can I reverse the email address using PHP or JS?

Comment: I'm not a PHP guy, but try the strrev() method: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php

Comment: ..this has just 1 problem, if someone try to copy'n'paste the email adress, he will see the reversed version, "moc.rab@oof"

Comment: as I commented below, any javascript manipulation will be defeated by robots doing full DOM render. You're best of with an image, or the recaptcha solution suggested here.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to look into [reCAPTCHA Mailhide](http://mailhide.recaptcha.net/). It should be easy to use from PHP.

Comment: this looks to be one of the best solutions i've seen. however, it does come with the cost of being a slight pain for the user

Comment: @Richard. Yes, for the users who will actually use the address, that is :)

Answer (score 2):

Obfuscation using trickiest possible HTML entities and urlencode, implemented in PHP: 
http://hcard.geekhood.net/encode/

Source: 
http://code.google.com/p/hcardvalidator/source/browse/trunk/encode/index.php

Another approach I use is:

```
<a href="mailto:me@myserver.removethis.com">
<script>[…] a.href = a.href.replace(/removethis\./,'');</script>
```

It's worth noting that both techniques give users perfectly accessible, clickable link.

Answer (score 2):

never write email addresses as text on webpages, NEVER!

and browser bots surely have JS enabled -_-

Comment: Maybe you dont believe, but many costumer want the emails to be ritten in the HTML, in text form. I warn them about the spam, but they simply dont care... well, the take care of it just 3 months later ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can try changing name@example.com to:
"name at example dot com".

However, robots can easily account for this.

Otherwise, you could display a dynamic image of the email address if you are truly motivated.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a perfect solution, but the Enkoder (http://hivelogic.com/enkoder) is quite useful for this. It uses Javascript to obfuscate the address.

Comment: this would be defeated by any robot which did a full DOM render

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So after a while, I've found this blog article on how to do this easily.
http://techblog.tilllate.com/2008/07/20/ten-methods-to-obfuscate-e-mail-addresses-compared/
And how much impact does it do on spam receiving ..

I guess this could be complementary to the info given above .. 
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Would this work as well??

Using something like this

```
<span>myaddress</span><span>@</span><span>mydomain.com</span>
```

This won't stand as a link, but would still be recognizable by the human eye on a page, and probably con't be parsed by a robot. Haven't checked it out, thou.
You could probably insert that string into a void  and bind it to a function that composes the address by parsing out the content ..

Just a fast thought ...

Comment: this would be picked up by any robot doing the minimum of DOM parsing

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to do. Unless you use an image, anything which is rendered human-readable by your browser can be rendered human-readable by a robot. So even scrambling the e-email in some way in the HTML source and then using a javascript function to de-scramble dynamically on page rendering, this will be defeated by a robot which also does full rendering of the DOM.

Until recently I had good success with the above method, and didn't see any spam. Recently however I have noticed that addresses do seem to have been picked up. So I can only assume e-mail trawlers are now doing full DOM rendering.

So to conclude - an image is probably best (although even that is not 100%)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple jquery solution to this problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    str1="mailto:";
    str2="info";
    str3="@test.com";
    $("#email_a").attr("href", str1+str2+str3);

});
</script>

<a href="#" id="email_a"><img src="sample.png"/></a>
```